# When formatting date object - does it matter that the T and the 000Z will be removed when storing to db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, formatdatetime

Sorry if its a very basic question but I dont understand the following:

When I format the Date object (no matter what library I used), I get a string.

```
from this: 2022-11-28T16:55:44.000Z (new Date object)
I get this: 2022-11-28 16:55:44 (or other formats obviously depending how I format it)
```

Even if I turn it back into an object it, the T and 000Z will never be there anymore. Do I just ignore that (seems like it as any library or date methods are ignoring the T and the string ending when formatting) or do I add it 'back' Isnt it a problem if dates stored in my db are different (for later queries etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it even stronger: You should **never** store dates as strings, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects. Here on SO you can find hundreds of questions, where people have problems, because they stored date values as (localized) strings. It is not limited to MongoDB, it applies to any database.

`Date` objects in MongoDB are UTC times - **always and only**! Usually the client application is responsible to display the date/time in local time zone and local format.

What do you mean by "turn it back", i.e. how do you do it?

You should not rely on `new Date(<string>)` without time zone. Some browsers/environments may apply UTC time, others may use current local time zone, see [Differences in assumed time zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#differences_in_assumed_time_zone)

Have a look at 3rd party date libraries, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon), or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/). Usually they provide better control how to parse strings and time zones.

Comment: thank you! If its common to store dates in mongo as UTC times, I wonder in this case: user posts reports with time+date (it will always be CET time, also not in browsers, its an app). I store reports as utc times and handle the times in my client (formatting to cet there). now lets say users could search for reports based on time, so when they pick the time+date for search I would format that into utc time again so my db can be queried with utc time. All that formatting, just to fit it to utc times even though the app is local and will always use cet times is right approach still?

Comment: Not fully clear what you mean. Let's say it like this: All processing, storing, etc. is done in UTC. Only the final display is done on local times.

Comment: ok I understand. Just a last question. I am now storing the dates without formatting them, thus in utc in mongo. I store it as a date object, not string (new Date(value)), whats stored is something like this: ISODate("2022-11-29T08:23:35.441+0000"). Why is the Z removed if its now all utc times?

Comment: That's how your application displays it, usually you can set this in the application preferences. Time zone `Z` is equivalent to time zone `0000`, `00:00` or `UTC`

Comment: ok thank you. and would you also store additionally the time offset ( new Date(value).getTimezoneOffset())?

Comment: Yes, if you need to preserve input timezone for whatever reason, then you must store it in a separate field. But I hardly see any reason for this, if you work only with local times.

Answer (score 3):

The `Z` indicates UTC (Coordinated Universal Time, also known as Greenwich Meridian Time), dropping that changes the meaning - unless your browser or server lives in the Greenwich time zone and it is winter (no daylight saving time).

You can convert back and forth between a `Date` object and a UTC string as follows (my browser lives in the Central European time zone):

```
> utc = '2022-11-28T16:55:44.000Z'
'2022-11-28T16:55:44.000Z'
> d = new Date(utc)
Mon Nov 28 2022 17:55:44 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
> d.toISOString()
'2022-11-28T16:55:44.000Z'
```

Alternatively, you can convert back and forth between a `Date` object and a formatted string in your browser's or server's time zone (the last line shows that my browser's format differs from yours):

```
> formatted = '2022-11-28 17:55:44'
'2022-11-28 17:55:44'
> d = new Date(formatted)
Mon Nov 28 2022 17:55:44 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
> d.toLocaleString()
'11/28/2022, 5:55:44 PM'
```

But you should not store the `Date` objects in this format in a database, unless you can guarantee that they are always read and written in the same time zone. For example, if you format a `Date` object with your browser (in CET) and store it, then someone else who reads it and converts it back to a `Date` object with their browser in the New Zealand time zone will see a wrong value. Also, dates like `9/11/2022` are ambiguous if the formatting rules are not clear (September 11th or November 9th?).

That's why I would prefer UTC strings when storing `Date` objects and use formatted strings only for outputting them to the user and for parsing user input.

Comment: so since i specifically dont want the UTC time but the CET time, its actually correct If I format the date that it gets dropped? so that I have a string that I store thats not 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z' but 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' ?

Comment: See my augmented answer.

Comment: @juliascoding "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" is completely ambiguous without a time zone attached. And mongo has a [dedicated Date type](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Date/), you shouldn't be storing dates as strings.